# Открывать дополнительно список в recyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, kotlin

Есть список `recyclerView`, в котором распологаются мои элементы. В некоторых(*которые содержат категории*) из них, есть кнопка нажатия.

Как по нажатию на данную кнопку возможно открывать список с этими категориями?

p.s: Обращаюсь к этим категориям `data[position].category`. Делаю аналог `expadableList` для `recycler'a`.

Answer (score 2):

Пример реализации адаптера для раскрывающихся списков с `RecyclerView`

В класс категории добавить параметр `expanded`:

```
public class ItemsGroup<T> {

    private List<T> items;

    private boolean expanded;

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    public void expand() {
        expanded = true;
    }

    public void collapse() {
        expanded = false;
    }
}
```

Затем в адаптере добавить метод для вычисления "плоского списка" и метод для раскрытия/сворачивания списка по нажатию:

```
public class RecyclerViewExpandableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ItemsGroup<?>> groups;

    private List<?> getFlatItemsList() {
        List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ItemsGroup<?> group : groups) {
            items.add(group);
            if (group.isExpanded()) {
                items.addAll(group.getItems());
            }
        }

        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getFlatItemsList().size();
    }

    private void onHeaderClicked(ItemsGroup<?> header) {
        int idx = getFlatItemsList().indexOf(header);
        if (header.isExpanded()) {
            header.collapse();
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(idx + 1, header.getItems().size());
        } else {
            header.expand();
            notifyItemRangeInserted(idx + 1, header.getItems().size());
        }
    }
}
```

Метод `onHeaderClicked` нужно вызывать в `OnClickListener`'е категории.